# Ports for ELK Set up

Tags: elk

I checked the document, so far I found those ports are needed to open ,
My questions Did I miss anything , are there more ports needed?

```
Logstash Ports 5044, 9600 and 9700

Kibana Port 5601

ElastichSearch Ports 9200, 9300
```

Thanks and Rgds